# Proper Disposal of SciChartSurface

Tags: c#, scichart

I'm currently using a similar structure to the [50 EEG example](https://www.scichart.com/example/wpf-chart-example-50-channel-eeg/). Part of my design is to add and delete 10-50 function plots on the fly, so it is important that I managed my memory effectively. When I run the memory profiler in VS2015, I find that everytime I try to a function plot from the collection, SciChart.Charting.Visuals.Axes.LabelProviders.NumericTickLabel still lingers in memory. What would be the proper way to dispose NumericTickLabel or remove a scichartsurface?

XAML.CS

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
       <DataTemplate x:Key="FunctionItemTemplate">
       <Grid>
           <s:SciChartSurface Name=FunctionSurface
                              RenderableSeries="{Binding RenderableSeriesCollections}"/>

       </Grid>
    </ResourceDictionary>

    <ListView Name="FunctionPlots
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FunctionItemTemplate}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding FunctionsCollection}" />
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyProperty
{
       private ObservableCollection<FunctionPlotViewModel> _functionsCollection;

       public MainWindowViewModel()
       {
           FunctionsCollection = new ObservableCollection<FunctionPlotViewModel>();
       }

       public ObservableCollection<FunctionPlotViewModel> FunctionsCollection
       {
             get { return _functionsCollection;}
             set 
             {
                   _functionsCollection = value;
                   OnPropertyChanged("FunctionsCollection");     
             }  
       }

       public void RemoveLastFunctionPlot()
       {
              int lastIndex = FunctionCollections.Count - 1;
              FunctionCollections.Remove(lastIndex);
              //Doesn't Collect
              GC.Collect();
              GC.WaitForPendingFinalizer();
              GC.Collect();
       }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHanlder PropertyChanged;
       protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
       {
                PropertyChangedEventHanlder handler = PropertyChanged;

                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

                }
        }

}
```

FunctionPlotViewModel.cs

```
 public class FunctionPlotViewModel: INotifyProperty
    {
       private ObservableCollection<IRenderableSeries> _renderableSeriesCollections;

       public FunctionPlotViewModel()
       {
           RenderableSeriesCollection = new ObservableCollection<IRenderableSeries>();
       }

       public ObservableCollection<IRenderableSeries> RenderableSeriesCollections
       {
             get { return _renderableSeriesCollections;}
             set 
             {
                   _renderableSeriesCollections= value;
                   OnPropertyChanged("RenderableSeriesCollections");     
             }  
       }

       public  void SetUpCustomAxis(double TimeOfDayInitial, IAxis AxisToBindTo)
       {
             var defaultSurface = RenderableSeriesCollections.FirstOrDefault().DataSeries.ParentSurface();
              if(defaultSurface == null)
              {
                  return;
              }
              var newAxis = new NumericAxis();
              var customNumericLabel = new CustomNumericLabelProvider();
              defaultSurface.XAxis = newAxis;
              Binding visibleRangeBinding = new Binding("VisibleRange");
              visibleRangeBinding.Source = AxisToBindTo;
              visibleRangeBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
              ((NumericAxis)defaultSurface.XAxis).SetBinding(NumericAxis.VisibleRangeProperty, visibleRangeBinding);

       }

       public void CleanUp()
       {
           var defaultSurface = RenderableSeriesCollections.FirstOrDefault().DataSeries.ParentSurface();
              if(defaultSurface == null)
              {
                  return;
              }
           foreach(var renderSeries in RenderableSeriesCollections)
           {
                renderSeries.DataSeries.Clear();
           }
           RenderableSeriesCollections.Clear();
           var token  = defaultSurface.SuspendUpdates();
           token.Dispose();

           //More things to do??
       }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHanlder PropertyChanged;
       protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
       {
                PropertyChangedEventHanlder handler = PropertyChanged;

                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

                }
        }

}
```

CustomNumericLabelProvider.cs

```
     public class CustomNumericLabelProvider : NumericProvider
     {
       public override void OnBeginAxisDraw()
       {
       }

       public override string FormatLabel(IComparable dataValue)
       {
            if (dataValue == null)
                return String.Emtpy;
            return ConvertToTimeOfDay(dataValue);

       }

       public string ConvertToTimeOfDay(IComparable value)
       {
             //commented out for brevity
             return value;
       }

       public override string FormatCursorLabel(IComparable dataValue)
       {
            //commented out for brevity
            return dataValue;
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the SciChart documentation, [SciChartSurface implements the Finalizer and Dispose patterns](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/SciChart.Charting~SciChart.Charting.Visuals.SciChartSurface~Dispose.html), which calls dispose on child elements when a chart is unloaded from memory.

The documentation also shows the [RenderSurface implements Finalize](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/SciChart.Drawing~SciChart.Drawing.Common.RenderSurfaceBase~Finalize.html) so resources should be automatically cleaned up when a chart is no longer held by any objects.

If you experience anything different, it is probably a bug.

The best thing to do is to check if you are using the [latest version of SciChart from their NuGet feed](https://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/17232/37/getting-nightly-builds-with-nuget), and after that, if the issue still occurs, to submit a bug report with code to reproduce the bug to [tech support](http://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Tickets/Submit).